# How to get key event on on lockscreen ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyevent

I want to get the Key events when someone try to unlock iphone, like keyup keydown event when they type their password for passcode ,

Comment: I dont get it when people have thumps down when they did not know the key reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, of course, if only for security reasons.

Just out of curiosity, why do you need that?

Comment: I came across kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly and tought it could help, but unsure. 
for your curiosity , I am a security researcher and working on a security application (Authentication mechanism  )

Comment: I am using it for my  research